# How does one expose and manipulate C# Runtime Objects for VB Scripting?

Tags: c#, object, vbscript, runtime

I am trying to make an application in C# which reads data in real time from a Serial Port.
The application would then allowsthe user to manipulate this data by means of a VB Script. The user is expected to be able to write a VBScript which would manipulate this data for his own purpose. Such VB statesments would be something like:

```
If CurrentTime = 12 then Stream.CurrentValue = 10
If CurrentTime = 1 then Stream.Enabled = False
```

Is it possible to expose aand manipualte C# objects during run time by a VB Script?

Can someone point me to the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: Adding user scripting to an application almost never ends well - the second you give users access to objects inside your application, **someone** will find a way to make it do something you don't want it to, so proceed with caution.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439